# How to left-right slider array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arraylist, slider

I have an array of pictures. And 2 buttons: left arrow and right arrow.

[image]

The length of the array is 60 pictures. By clicking on the right button, the picture is redrawn. From 21 to 40 pictures.

```html
function lotLoad() {
    const count = Math.min(lots.length, getCount(window.innerWidth).extra);
    const extraMovies = lots.slice(count * (currentTab-1), count * currentTab);

    setLotsSplice([]);
    setLotsSplice([...extraMovies]);

    setCurrentCount(count * currentTab + 1);
    setcurrentTab(currentTab + 1);

    checkDisableArrowsBtn();
}
```

The currentTab variable reflects the current tab number.
On the last 3rd page On the last 3rd page = 3.

But when I scroll to the left, the array is displayed incorrectly and another Onclick event  on the right button and  currentTab = 4,  but I dont click button_right again.

```html
const renderL = () => {
    const count = Math.min(lots.length, getCount(window.innerWidth).extra);
    const extraMovies = lots.slice(currentCount - count* (currentTab)-1, count*currentTab - currentCount + 1);

    setLotsSplice([]);
    setLotsSplice([...extraMovies]);

    setCurrentCount(currentCount - count*(currentTab-1)-1);

    setcurrentTab(currentTab - 1);


}
```

Help, please, make flipping left and right by copying and drawing only part of the array of pictures.
For example, on the second tab, only pictures from 21 to 40 should be drawn, which are taken from the original array.